# general equations solving

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Is there any general method of how to solve equation $\frac{A}{x^\alpha}+\frac{B}{x^\beta}+\frac{C}{x^\gamma}=D$ for $A,B,C,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in R$ $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$

Even approximate solution, just with a general algorithm.

I can see that if f.e. $\alpha$ is the largest of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $A\cdot D<0$, then there might be no solutions.

Comment: This is equivalent to a polynomial equation, so there is no analytical method (except for a limited number of rational exponents), only numerical approaches.

Comment: And numerical approach can be any of the well-known ones, e.g., Newton's method, etc.

Comment: @user202729, @ YvesDaoust ok, thank you guys!